# either because or because

Tags: conjunctions, run-on-sentences

Is this a right way to say that something is not happening because of these reasons? Also, how to say if there are more than two reasons when talking (not writing)?

**"Thousands of software bugs are not fixed. And this is because either we can't prove them as bugs because we don't know how to reproduce the issue again because it happened only once and we didn't collect much information when that happened or because someone thought it was bug only to find later that it was only some configurational issue"**

I find it as very long sentence with lot/lots of because/becauses.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly confusing, but it's not wrong. The sentence is structured like this:

> This is because either A or because B.

If there are three reasons, you can say it like this:

> This is because either A, B, or because C.

These are also acceptable:

> This is because either A, B, or C.
>
> This is either because A, B, or C.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid the chain of "because". You can use parentheses for that. I'd also re-phrase much of that text.

**"Thousands of software bugs are not fixed. This results from either not being able to prove them as bugs (due to failure to reproduce the issue, as a result of failure to collect sufficient information on an issue that only occurred once) or from supposed bugs which later turn out to be a configuration issue."**